# Connect ASPNET Core web application to a Sql Server database through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sql-server-2016, azure-aks

I have an ASPNET .Core application running on a pod in Kubernetes in AKS. The pod's network is an Azure's private network that is linked to my company's on-premise network via VPN.
The web application at runtime connects to different SQL Server DB instances that reside both on the Azure's private network and on the company's on-premise network (I cannot move those on the Azure's network).

The problem that I have is that the web application can access the SQL Server instances that reside on the Azure private network but cannot reach the on-premise's ones. To solve the problems I was thinking to enable a Squid SOCKS proxy on the Azure network that would proxy all the connections to the SQL Servers in the company network. I used this same method to let the application connect to some HTTP services that reside on the company's network using a Squid HTTP proxy, and it's working.

The question is, how to configure the .net core application in order to let it use the SOCKS proxy when using the [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class?
This is how currently I connect to the DBs

```
using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        results.Add(tupleHandler(reader));
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

Thank you

Comment: I understand this is not directly answering your question, and is a pretty long shot. just wondering if you checked whether [gateway transit feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#gateways-and-on-premises-connectivity) can help you establish connectivity

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server works over tcp protocol, so solution over http-proxy will not work.
As @timur said you need to expose your SQL endpoint over some hybrid VPN gateway. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54822402/603622) should lead you in the right direction