# Azure App Service integration with SQL Server in VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an dotnet app which is running in azure app service and my data base is running on Azure Vm (IAAS), now i would like to access my application with SQL Server which is running on vm.

What is the recommended solution to achieve above, should i use private endpoint or service endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow your app service to access the database in the VM, you need to [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). VNet Integration gives your app access to resources in your VNet, but it doesn't grant inbound private access to your app from the VNet. VNet Integration is used only to make outbound calls from your app into your VNet.

If you need to expose your app on a private IP in your virtual network. You could use [Private Endpoints for Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint).

More References:

- [Connecting an Azure WebApp to a SQL Server VM inside a VNet](https://connectedcircuits.blog/2020/04/23/connecting-an-azure-webapp-to-a-sql-server-vm-inside-a-vnet/)
- [App Service networking features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features)

Comment: in this case how Hybrid connections work Nancy?

Comment: You can use hybrid connections to connect app service to the SQL server on Azure VM just like you connect it to on-premise SQL Server, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821962/connect-to-on-prem-sql-server-from-azure-web-app). In this case, you don't need VNet integration and private endpoint. Within App Service, Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in any network that can make outbound calls to Azure over port 443.

Comment: Thank you nancy for the response. appreciate.

Comment: Do you still have any questions?

Comment: No nancy i am good now. i have cleared my ambiguity. thq