# Is it possible to setup an Azure Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM) on an on-premise Linux box?

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, ssh, port

[image]

In the above picture (taken from link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) we see a Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM) installed on an on-premise box. At that link it seems the on-premise box is a windows box. Is it possible to get the same setup on an on-premise Linux box? For this particular use case I need to call into a MySQL instance (running on port 3306) on the Linux box via SSH tunnelling forwarded port from my C# Asp.net REST Web Api in an Azure App Service Api App. The Api App can't make the call because one can't get a local bound forwarded port on an Azure App Service Plan due to the fact that only ports 80 and 443 are open...all other local ports are closed by default on an Azure App Service Plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that we can not install the Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM) on an on-premise Linux box. [The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#hybrid-connection-manager) stated that *this tool runs on Windows Server 2012 and later. The HCM runs as a service and connects outbound to Azure Relay on port 443.*

In fact, the Hybrid Connections feature requires a relay agent **in the network** that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint. In this case, you could install a relay agent on a Windows box in the same network that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint. The reply agent calls out to Azure Relay over port 443. For more details, you could [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821962/connect-to-on-prem-sql-server-from-azure-web-app).

> The solution here is to ensure that you are using the hostname of your
> on-premise server rather than the fully-qualified domain name. If you
> are using a fully-qualified domain name, you need to ensure that it’s
> a name that can be resolved within your local network. (In some cases,
> customers are running DNS in the local network, and it’s that local
> DNS service that resolves the name.)